как узнать есть ли у пользователя доступ в группу telethon
у меня есть скрипт который отправляет сообщение в определённую группу, в которой я не являюсь админом.
как проверить могу ли я писать в эту группу на Python (забанен ли я в ней, и состою ли я в ней)

Отправить туда сообщение и перехватить исключение, очевидно

@ClarkDevlin а если окажется что да, то сообщение то отправиться.

@чистов_n ну так скрипт автора и отправляет же сообщение, если отправил - значит в группе, если нет, то в зависимости от исключения делаем выводы

@ClarkDevlin ну да в этом случае работает.
